# how to remove a classList when I select another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

When I click on an 'imposter' I want it to become grey with some text as you can see in my CSS with the selector `.imposter.voted`. But when I click another imposter I want that one to appear grey and the previous one to appear like usual again.

When I try `this.classList.remove("voted")` it does not work and it just makes all the imposters I select grey. The class does not get removed. I don't see where I went wrong.

```js
imposters = document.querySelectorAll(".imposter");

for (let i = 0; i < imposters.length; i++) {
  imposters[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("voted");
  });
}
```

```css
.imposter.voted {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.imposter.voted::after {
  content: "I voted";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Comic Sans Ms";
  color: red;
}

.imposters__voting {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<main class="dashboard">
  <h1>Who Is The Imposter?</h1>
  <div class="imposters">
    <div class="imposter">Baba</div>
    <div class="imposter">Baraki</div>
    <div class="imposter">Garfield</div>
    <div class="imposter">Erik</div>
    <div class="imposter">GreenBlood4</div>
    <div class="imposter">Easter</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: There's no `this.classList.remove("voted")` in your script. Please add an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `.voted` from all the `div.imposter` if present then add `.voted` class to the clicked element.

```js
imposters = document.querySelectorAll(".imposter");

for (let i = 0; i < imposters.length; i++) {
  imposters[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var count = 0;
    while(count<imposters.length){
      imposters[count++].classList.remove('voted');
    }
    this.classList.add("voted");
  });
}
```

```css
.imposter.voted {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.imposter.voted::after {
  content: "I voted";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Comic Sans Ms";
  color: red;
}

.imposters__voting {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<main class="dashboard">
  <h1>Who Is The Imposter?</h1>
  <div class="imposters">
    <div class="imposter">Baba</div>
    <div class="imposter">Baraki</div>
    <div class="imposter">Garfield</div>
    <div class="imposter">Erik</div>
    <div class="imposter">GreenBlood4</div>
    <div class="imposter">Easter</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remember the index of the currently selected imposter in a variable `currentIndex`. Then after clicking you need to go through the rest of the imposters and remove the class `voted`.

```js
let imposters = document.querySelectorAll(".imposter");

let currentIndex = null;

for (let i = 0; i < imposters.length; i++) {
  imposters[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("voted");
    
    currentIndex = i;
    
    imposters.forEach(function(imposter, index){
        if(index != currentIndex) {
            imposter.classList.remove("voted"); 
        }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.imposter.voted {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.imposter.voted::after {
  content: "I voted";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Comic Sans Ms";
  color: red;
}

.imposters__voting {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<main class="dashboard">
  <h1>Who Is The Imposter?</h1>
  <div class="imposters">
    <div class="imposter">Baba</div>
    <div class="imposter">Baraki</div>
    <div class="imposter">Garfield</div>
    <div class="imposter">Erik</div>
    <div class="imposter">GreenBlood4</div>
    <div class="imposter">Easter</div>
  </div>
</main>
```